# how to retrieve magnetic value from CLHeading

Tags: iphone, cllocationmanager

i'm trying with CLHeading to get compass value,

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading {
 if (curHeading != nil)
  [curHeading release];

 curHeading = newHeading;
 NSLog(@"%@",curHeading);
 [curHeading retain];
}
```

the above give result as  -

> magneticHeading 89.00 trueHeading +103.27 accuracy 5.00 x +1.375 y
>   +41.875 z +37.438 @ 2010-01-18 10:18:37 +0800

but i need just the magneticHeading value, so

i alter the code as :

a)

> newHeading.magneticHeading -> got result null

b)

> newHeading.trueHeading     -> Program received signal: 
>   “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.

can anyone help, i just trying with other possible way to get the compass value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

magneticHeading and trueHeading are both of type CLLocationDirection, which is actually  a double. If you want to NSLog() a double, you have to use "%f", or "%.9f", not "%@", which is for objects.